# Binding to an object property with dots in the name

Tags: ember.js

I need to bind to an object property called

```
errors : {
  'name.content' : {
      presence : true
   }
}
```

I can't figure out how to do this as the below does not work.

```
errorsBinding : 'controller.errors["name.content"]'
```

I don't have control over name of the object property `name.content` as it is part of ember-validations so I can't change it to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working

```
errorsBinding : 'controller.errors.name\.content'
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you could escape the dot with `\` as:

```
errorsBinding : 'controller.errors["name\.content"]'
```